# delete node from project csproj

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

My project.csproj file contain below three compile include . i wanted to delete all three compile include at once.

```
<Compile Include="Orkut\Cart\Cart.Designer.cs">
<AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
<DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
<DependentUpon>Cart.resx"></DependentUpon>
 </Compile>

<Compile Include="Orkut\Cart\Cart.Designer.de-DE.cs">
<AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
<DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
<DependentUpon>Cart.de-DE.resx"></DependentUpon>
 </Compile>

<Compile Include="Orkut\Cart\Cart.Designer.sv-SE.cs">
<AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
<DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
<DependentUpon>Cart.sv-SE.resx"></DependentUpon>
 </Compile>
```

i have written code for this but it is deleting after checking the value

```
  string fileName=@"D:\projectpath\abc.csproj";
     XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";

        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

 var b1 = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "Compile")
            .Where(el => el.Attribute("Include").Value == @"Orkut\abc.Designer.cs");
if (b1 != null)
        {
            b1.Remove();

            xDoc.Save(fileName);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`IEnumerable<T>.Remove()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554.aspx) extension to remove every matching node from its parent node:

```
xDoc.Descendants(ns + "Compile")
    .Where(el => (string)el.Attribute("Include") == @"Orkut\abc.Designer.cs")
    .Remove();

xDoc.Save(fileName);
```

If you want to delete all `Compile` elements which has include containing `Orkut\Cart\Cart.Designer` then use following condition to select those elements:

```
Where(e => e.Attribute("Include").Value.StartsWith(@"Orkut\Cart\Cart.Designer"))
```

Comment: i have already done but i want how to get all three compile include at once to delete

Comment: @user2682769 that removes all compiles which have Include equal to `Orkut\abc.Designer.cs`. If you want to remove all compiles which have any Include value, use `Where(el => el.Attribute("Include") != null)`